# Why are cuts made with BoxCutter appearing as objects in an Octane render?

Tags: modeling, rendering, octane-render-engine

Whenever I cut stuff off using the box cutter, it works fine in blender but then it creates geometry instead of cutting it when I render it in octane. As you can see in the pic there's a little cube that was added in octane where I cut away in blender. It basically does the opposite of what the boxcutter should do. Any help would be super appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you applying the modifier from the cut before rendering?

It looks like Octane is rendering the shape created by Boxcutter, which exists in non-destructive model until you click *Apply*.

Comment: I fixed it by changing export options but that should work as well, thank you! :)